# Portrait layout of my app is drawing View larger than it should

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-progressbar, android-relativelayout

I have 2 layouts for the primary screen of a small app I built.  One layout is for portrait and one layout is for landscape.

The landscape version looks just how I want it.

[image: landscape]

Here is the XML code for this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    tools:context=".Main">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/consumption_progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
            android:secondaryProgress="100" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/time_progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar2"
            android:secondaryProgress="100" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/water_consumed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/water_consumed"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/milliliters_abbrev"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/glass"
                style="@style/ButtonSmall"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/whitebutton_small"
                android:text="@string/glass"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacer"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacer" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/custom"
                style="@style/ButtonSmall"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/whitebutton_small"
                android:text="@string/custom"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacer"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacer" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/small_bottle"
                style="@style/ButtonSmall"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/whitebutton_small"
                android:text="@string/small_bottle"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacer"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacer" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/large_bottle"
                style="@style/ButtonSmall"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/whitebutton_small"
                android:text="@string/large_bottle"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The portrait XML is the exact same XML except the top-most `LinearLayout` has `android:orientation="vertical"` added to it.

However, when in portrait mode, the progress bars size themselves bigger than the view that contains them.

[image]

I suspect this is because half of the screen is not a perfect square, and the `View` containing the `ProgressBar` should be a square.  Does anyone know how to accomplish my goal here?

Comment: Post the the XML of portrait  layout pls

Comment: It is the exact same exception `android:orientation="vertical"` has been added to the top level `View`.

Comment: have you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem it takes max(width, height) in the `onMeasure` and sets the bigger one. The solution is to simply extend the ProgressBar and override the onMeasure method

```
public class CustomProgressBar extends ProgressBar {
    public CustomProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        int min = Math.min(width, height);
        setMeasuredDimension(min, min);
    }
}
```

Antother way would be tut put it in a horizontal LinearLayout and placing a dummy view 15% width to the left and a dummy view 15% (or whatever is good for you) to the right of it.

for your comment and weird situation can you try:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/water_consumed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/water_consumed"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="@string/milliliters_abbrev"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: If this is the problem, wouldn't it also happen in landscape mode, too?

Comment: It does seem to work.  However, the `TextView`s I have in the center seem to no longer be centered.

Comment: For some reason they are centered on landscape but now off-centered in portrait.

Comment: that is weird indeed, can you try what I posted now?

Comment: It centered the `TextView`, but moved the `ProgressBar` to the left

Comment: I tried adding `layoutCenterInParent` to the `ProgressBar`s, but that didn't help.

Comment: Oh my god :/ Maybe FrameLayout will solve the issue Maybe the progressbar is fighting with the TextViews for space and that was your problem in the first place.